# Exercise 17.2 of Matsumura about CM rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have two questions about this exercise of Matsumura:
[image]

Question 1: Why $y^3$ is $R/(x^3)$ regular?

Question 2: I hardly (in 20 lines) can prove that $k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$ is not CM. Is there a short way or intuition for this part ?

Answer (score 3):

For the second question, note that $x^4, y^4$ is a SOP (system of parameters). Since $R=k[x^4, x^3y,xy^3, y^4]$ is a domain, $x^4$ is a non-zero divisor on $R$. But observe that $y^4$ is a zero divisor on $R/(x^4)$ because $y^4(x^3y)^2=x^4(xy^3)^2$. Of course, one needs to note that $(x^3y)^2\notin (x^4)$. Hence $R$ is not CM.

Added Later: For the first part, you can write $A$ as $$k[X,Y,Z,W]/(XW-YZ,Z^3-XW^2,Y^3-X^2W,XZ^3-Y^3W).$$ Now note that $X, W$ form a SOP, and that $W$ is regular on $$A/(X)=k[Y,Z,W]/(YZ,Z^3,Y^3,Y^3W).$$

Comment: Writing $A$ as a quotient of a polynomial ring is much more difficult to prove than the problem itself.

Comment: @user26857, True but since the hint provided was not sufficient and since i did not want to give more than that as it is a homework, i took this route so that the OP can hopefully see why $y^3$ is $R/(x^3)$ regular, but perhaps i might have complicated things for the OP, i dont know. But you are absolutely right.

Comment: @user114539: can you please explain the "Added Later" part?

Comment: @seddigh What part. Just try to write the ring as a quotient(which is the hard part) and then check that $x,w$ is a SOP and that it does not form a regular sequence.

Comment: how to write the ring as a quotient